# How to setup puma server for Rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, webrick

I am working on Rails 2.3.18 running on WEBrick, now i want to move to puma

is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  the standard settings?

> `gem install puma`
>
> `puma <any rackup (*.ru) file>`

At the point after you install it you probably gonna have some bugs, I found some solution on the documentation:

[image]

https://github.com/puma/puma